# Laravel 5.1 Radio Buttons and Checkboxes

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

In a Laravel blade template,  we have a form with some optional radio buttons and check boxes, like

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="A" name="A">A <br />
 <input type="checkbox" id="B" name="B">B <br />
```

and radio buttons

```
 <input type="radio" id="R1" name="AINE" value="1"> Yes
 <input type="radio" id="R2" name="AINE" value="0"> No
```

In controller, in post method, we have

```
$input = Input::all();
DB::connection('datab1')->table('tab1')->insert(array(    
'A' => array_key_exists('A', $input) ? $input['A'] : null,
'B' => array_key_exists('B', $input) ? $input['B'] : null,
'AINE' => array_key_exists('AINE', $input) ? $input['AINE'] : null,
 ));
```

But on submitting the form, it always insert 1 in all the three columns in database, even if NONE of the radio button is selected, or checkbox is checked. Can somebody please explain?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your check boxes or radio buttons in array mode forexample:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="A" name="A[]">A <br />
```

and foreach your array in your controller like this:

```
foreach(Input::get('A') as $name)
{
   $model=new yourModelName;
   $model->yourRowName=$name;
   $model->save(); 
    return->redirect()->back();
 }
```

And its finished.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like the following:

```
public function post(Request $request)
{
    DB::connection('datab1')
        ->table('tab1')
        ->insert([    
            'A' => $request->has('A') ? $request->A : null,
            'B' => $request->has('B') ? $request->B : null,
            'AINE' => $request->has('AINE') ? $request->AINE : null,
        ]
    );
}
```